# Mask zero values in matrix and reconstruct original matrix using indices

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix

In case we have

```
indice=[0 0 1 1 0 1];
```

and

```
X=[0 0 0;0 0 0;5 8 9;10 11 12; 0 0 0; 20 3 4],
```

i would like to use indice to mask 0 value in X and get `Xx=[5 8 9;10 11 12; 20 3 4]`, and then from Xx, we back to initial dimension `newX=[0 0 0;0 0 0;5 8 9;10 11 12; 0 0 0; 20 3 4]`

```
for i in range(3):
    a=X[:,i];
Xx[:,i]=a[indice];
```

--and back to initial dimension:

```
  for ii in range(3)
    aa=Xx[:,ii]
    bb[indice]=aa
    newX[:,ii]=bb
```

could you help me please to solve that  with python?

Comment: how do you define the `indice ` ?

Comment: indice is just an input vector with 0 and 1 values

Comment: you have 5 and 2 inside. Correct your question

Comment: thanks for the remark :)

Comment: do you really need to use the specific `indice ` or it's okay to define it in another way? e.g. using `np.where` ?

Comment: if i used np.where, how can i back to initial dimension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpy.where` the life is much easier.

```
X=np.array([[0 ,0 ,0],[0, 0, 0],[5, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12],[ 0, 0 ,0],[ 20, 3, 4]])

index = np.where(X.any(axis=1))[0] # find rows with all 0s

print(X[index])
#array([[ 5,  8,  9],
#       [10, 11, 12],
#       [20,  3,  4]])
```

**EDIT:**

If you really want to reconstruct it, and based on the fact that you know that you have removed lines with all 0s, then:

Create a new matrix with all 0s:

```
X_new = np.zeros(X.shape)
```

and insert the values where they should be:

```
X_new[index] = X[index]
```

Now check the `X_new`:

```
X_new

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  8.,  9.],
       [10., 11., 12.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [20.,  3.,  4.]])
```

Comment: thanks :D
thats the first part, in case, we want back to initial dimension , i mean from print(X[index]) to X=np.array([[0 ,0 ,0],[0, 0, 0],[5, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12],[ 0, 0 ,0],[ 20, 3, 4]]). do you have any idea how we could do that ?

Comment: yes. see my updated answer. consider accepting my answer please